# I want to put a header on my poster

Tags: graphics, header-footer, posters, footer, wide-image

I'm working on a poster for a congress, and I need to put an image as a header. The problem is that I can't supreme the margins in the image, and I don't know how.

This is my code:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textheight]{RCI_Header.png}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
```

and the first image is what I get, the second one is what I want.

Thank you in advance.
[image: This is what I get][image: This is What I want]

Comment: The obvious thing is width=\textwidth, but there are other issues.  First, are you only going to do this on one page?  The 80pt \headheight is permanent.

Comment: If this is a (one page) poster, fancyhdr is not the way to go.  See tikzposter for examplle.

Answer (score 1):

This solution does not preserve the aspect ratio.  Also, it seems that fancyhdr includes a `\strut` in the header, hence the `\raisebox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\dimexpr \headheight-80pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\chead{\raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=80pt]{example-image}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\centerline{this page intentionally left blank}
\end{document}
```